# Android: Display pop-up menu on certain action?

Tags: android, menu, popup, contextmenu

Ok so I know you can create a context menu when a user long clicks on an item...but can I make it so the pop-up menu appears when a user lets say double taps on the item or screen? Thanks

Comment: "Pop-up windows" in Android are called Dialogs. You should look those up.

Comment: Just to clarify. popupWindows in android are called PopupWindow, Dialogs are called dialogs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html.  Popupwindows are really a floating view thus are not attached to backtag and lifecycle of fragment manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could show an alert dialog like this:

```
private void showDialog()
{
   final CharSequence[] options = {"Option1", "Option2", "etc.."};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title here");

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
           if (which == 0)//Option 1
           {
           }
           else if (which == 1)//Option 2
           {
           }
           //etc..
        } 
    });

    AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
   dlg.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you detect the gesture you want you can invoke [`showContextMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#showContextMenu%28%29) on the appropriate View which will use the same mechanisms as the context menus you're already familiar with. You should try to stay consistent with the platform when possible though. :)